# Why $ e^{-2\pi} \neq 1? $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the following:
$$
e^{2 \pi i} = 1
$$

$$
\left(e^{2 \pi i}\right)^i = 1^i
$$

$$
e^{2 \pi i^2} = 1
$$

$$
e^{-2 \pi} = 1
$$

but calculator tells me that: $\quad e^{-2 \pi} = 0.0018674427317...$

Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: You need to know the definition of $z^c$ where $c$ is complex.

Comment: The identity $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ does not hold in general.

Comment: The complex "function" $z \to z^i$ is a multi-valued function. In the case of $z = 1$, $z^i$ can take the value of $e^{2k\pi}$ for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, depending on the Riemann sheet you are working on. You simply chose a different sheet on the LHS than on the RHS.

Comment: Maybe we should have a system that directs all this questions to the almost uncountable bank of questions that end up with "The definition of $z^w$ is...".

Comment: You have complex powers defined by $z^w=e^{w\cdot Log \space z}$ where $Log\space z=\log|z|+i\arg\space z$. It follows 

$$LHS: (e^{2\pi i})^i=e^{i(\log|1|+i2\pi})=e^{-2\pi}\\RHS:\space 1^i=e^{i(\log|1|+i \frac{\pi}{2})}=e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
Thus the inequality